# Scheduled Task Stopped suddenly

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2003

I am going through an issue where a scheduled task was set up by a user. It is being executed multiple times a day from Mon to Sun. It was having no trouble and was being executed on its time. But recently it stopped the execution, there was no change in any of its setting.

Since it is a production server(Windows Server 2003) we made a replica of scripts and scheduled(Hoping, a difference in time won't bother the job) them in a new task with my credentials, which is executing correctly.

I was doubting on logging and email but there is no issue as the new job is doing this correctly. What else could be the reason for the original job to be stopped?

**Update:**
Functionality : This job fetches some text files from SFTP server, process them all to show data on a WebSite. After completing each step, it sends an alert of confirmation. Though logging is less but it contains information about what all feeds have been processed.

In addition to that, Event log shows an information of execution of DTS package, written for this job.

Comment: Potentially if the original job hung it wouldn't retrigger until the previous run has completed. Ideally we'd need to see what the job was trying to achieve

Comment: @Oliver Hemsted - It seems the job is not starting at all.

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether you have set the Timeout for SFTP connection. I think its due to connection issue and connection taking time long/infinite time to respond back. In case if we dint set the timeout value then current running thread will get hung.